# Maven project(compile) - package snoozesoft.systray4j does not exist (Intellij Idea)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven

Пытаюсь компилировать свой проект, в который добавил через Project Structure - плагин snoozesoft.systray4j ([http://systray.sourceforge.net](http://systray.sourceforge.net/))

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>TaskManager</groupId>
    <artifactId>TaskManager</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <outputDirectory>target</outputDirectory>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>8.4.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>


    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jfoenix</groupId>
            <artifactId>jfoenix</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Выдает ошибки:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects... [WARNING]  [WARNING] Some problems
were encountered while building the effective model for
TaskManager:TaskManager:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT [WARNING]
'build.plugins.plugin.version' for
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing. @ line 22,
column 21 [WARNING]  [WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these
problems because they threaten the stability of your build. [WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer
support building such malformed projects. [WARNING]  [INFO]           
[INFO]
------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Building TaskManager 1.0-SNAPSHOT [INFO]
------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO]  [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources
(default-resources) @ TaskManager --- [WARNING] Using platform
encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is
platform dependent! [INFO] Copying 4 resources [INFO]  [INFO] ---
maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ TaskManager ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module! [WARNING] File
encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build
is platform dependent! [INFO] Compiling 11 source files to
C:\NetCracker\TaskManager\target [INFO]
------------------------------------------------------------- [ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :  [INFO]
------------------------------------------------------------- [ERROR] /C:/NetCracker/TaskManager/src/main/java/SysTray.java:[7,1] package
snoozesoft.systray4j does not exist [ERROR]
/C:/NetCracker/TaskManager/src/main/java/SysTray.java:[15,9] cannot
find symbol   symbol:   class SysTrayMenuItem   location: class
SysTray [ERROR]
/C:/NetCracker/TaskManager/src/main/java/SysTray.java:[15,40] cannot
find symbol   symbol:   class SysTrayMenuItem   location: class
SysTray [ERROR]
/C:/NetCracker/TaskManager/src/main/java/SysTray.java:[16,45] cannot
find symbol   symbol:   class SysTrayMenuListener   location: class
SysTray [ERROR]
/C:/NetCracker/TaskManager/src/main/java/SysTray.java:[33,9] cannot
find symbol   symbol:   class SysTrayMenuItem   location: class
SysTray [ERROR]
/C:/NetCracker/TaskManager/src/main/java/SysTray.java:[33,48] cannot
find symbol   symbol:   class SysTrayMenuItem   location: class
SysTray [ERROR]
/C:/NetCracker/TaskManager/src/main/java/SysTray.java:[35,9] cannot
find symbol   symbol:   class SysTrayMenuItem   location: class
SysTray [ERROR]
/C:/NetCracker/TaskManager/src/main/java/SysTray.java:[35,46] cannot
find symbol   symbol:   class SysTrayMenuItem   location: class
SysTray [ERROR]
/C:/NetCracker/TaskManager/src/main/java/SysTray.java:[37,9] cannot
find symbol   symbol:   class SysTrayMenuItem   location: class
SysTray [ERROR]
/C:/NetCracker/TaskManager/src/main/java/SysTray.java:[37,43] cannot
find symbol   symbol:   class SysTrayMenuItem   location: class
SysTray [ERROR]
/C:/NetCracker/TaskManager/src/main/java/SysTray.java:[38,48] cannot
find symbol   symbol:   class SysTrayMenuListener   location: class
SysTray [ERROR]
/C:/NetCracker/TaskManager/src/main/java/SysTray.java:[66,16] cannot
find symbol   symbol:   class SysTrayMenuItem   location: class
SysTray [ERROR]
/C:/NetCracker/TaskManager/src/main/java/SysTray.java:[71,9] cannot
find symbol   symbol:   class SysTrayMenuIcon   location: class
SysTray [ERROR]
/C:/NetCracker/TaskManager/src/main/java/SysTray.java:[71,40] cannot
find symbol   symbol:   class SysTrayMenuIcon   location: class
SysTray [ERROR]
/C:/NetCracker/TaskManager/src/main/java/SysTray.java:[72,13] cannot
find symbol   symbol:   class SysTrayMenu   location: class SysTray
[INFO] 15 errors  [INFO]
------------------------------------------------------------- [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] BUILD FAILURE [INFO]
------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total time: 5.750 s [INFO] Finished at:
2017-11-18T23:26:27+04:00 [INFO] Final Memory: 11M/27M [INFO]
------------------------------------------------------------------------ [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile
(default-compile) on project TaskManager: Compilation failure:
Compilation failure: [ERROR]
/C:/NetCracker/TaskManager/src/main/java/SysTray.java:[7,1] package
snoozesoft.systray4j does not exist [ERROR]
/C:/NetCracker/TaskManager/src/main/java/SysTray.java:[15,9] cannot
find symbol [ERROR] symbol:   class SysTrayMenuItem [ERROR] location:
class SysTray [ERROR]
/C:/NetCracker/TaskManager/src/main/java/SysTray.java:[15,40] cannot
find symbol [ERROR] symbol:   class SysTrayMenuItem [ERROR] location:
class SysTray [ERROR]
/C:/NetCracker/TaskManager/src/main/java/SysTray.java:[16,45] cannot
find symbol [ERROR] symbol:   class SysTrayMenuListener [ERROR]
location: class SysTray [ERROR]
/C:/NetCracker/TaskManager/src/main/java/SysTray.java:[33,9] cannot
find symbol [ERROR] symbol:   class SysTrayMenuItem [ERROR] location:
class SysTray [ERROR]
/C:/NetCracker/TaskManager/src/main/java/SysTray.java:[33,48] cannot
find symbol [ERROR] symbol:   class SysTrayMenuItem [ERROR] location:
class SysTray [ERROR]
/C:/NetCracker/TaskManager/src/main/java/SysTray.java:[35,9] cannot
find symbol [ERROR] symbol:   class SysTrayMenuItem [ERROR] location:
class SysTray [ERROR]
/C:/NetCracker/TaskManager/src/main/java/SysTray.java:[35,46] cannot
find symbol [ERROR] symbol:   class SysTrayMenuItem [ERROR] location:
class SysTray [ERROR]
/C:/NetCracker/TaskManager/src/main/java/SysTray.java:[37,9] cannot
find symbol [ERROR] symbol:   class SysTrayMenuItem [ERROR] location:
class SysTray [ERROR]
/C:/NetCracker/TaskManager/src/main/java/SysTray.java:[37,43] cannot
find symbol [ERROR] symbol:   class SysTrayMenuItem [ERROR] location:
class SysTray [ERROR]
/C:/NetCracker/TaskManager/src/main/java/SysTray.java:[38,48] cannot
find symbol [ERROR] symbol:   class SysTrayMenuListener [ERROR]
location: class SysTray [ERROR]
/C:/NetCracker/TaskManager/src/main/java/SysTray.java:[66,16] cannot
find symbol [ERROR] symbol:   class SysTrayMenuItem [ERROR] location:
class SysTray [ERROR]
/C:/NetCracker/TaskManager/src/main/java/SysTray.java:[71,9] cannot
find symbol [ERROR] symbol:   class SysTrayMenuIcon [ERROR] location:
class SysTray [ERROR]
/C:/NetCracker/TaskManager/src/main/java/SysTray.java:[71,40] cannot
find symbol [ERROR] symbol:   class SysTrayMenuIcon [ERROR] location:
class SysTray [ERROR]
/C:/NetCracker/TaskManager/src/main/java/SysTray.java:[72,13] cannot
find symbol [ERROR] symbol:   class SysTrayMenu [ERROR] location:
class SysTray [ERROR] -> [Help 1] [ERROR]  [ERROR] To see the full
stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch. [ERROR]
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging. [ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions,
please read the following articles: [ERROR] [Help 1]
http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Вторая проблема: при перезапуске проекта (закрыть - открыть idea) проект вообще не запускается, приходится "редактировать" pom.xml - нажимать дальше import settings, после этого только проект запускается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

К сожалению net.sourceforge не выложили данный проект в свой репозиторий.

Подключенный через projectStructure, он не попадает в собранный jar, точнее jar даже собраться не может.

Вы можете добавить jar в свой локальный репозиторий

```
mvn install:install-file
   -Dfile=<path-to-file>
   -DgroupId=<group-id>
   -DartifactId=<artifact-id>
   -Dversion=<version>
   -Dpackaging=<packaging>
   -DgeneratePom=true

Где: <path-to-file>  путь к jar, который надо загрузить
   <group-id>      group-id под которым вы его регистрируете
   <artifact-id>   artifact-id под которым вы его регистрируете
   <version>       версия проекта
   <packaging>     упаковка проекта т.е. jar
```

данные впишите уникальные, предлагаю такие:

```
group-id = net.sourceforge
artifact-id = systray
version = 1.0
packaging = jar
```

Тогда в своем проекте вы сможете добавить зависимость:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge</groupId>
        <artifactId>systray</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

И по идее должно заработать. Но на другой машине вы не сможете его собрать, без добавления jar в локальный репозиторий.

---

[Оригинал](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955635/how-to-add-local-jar-files-to-a-maven-project)

[Инфо](http://maven.apache.org/general.html#importing-jars)

Comment: Не знаете как быть со второй проблемой?

Comment: @Youlfey опишите конкретно проблему: какую ошибку выдает, что редактируете, как выглядит pom до и после редактирования.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/hc7b2p это при запуске проекте, когда я удаляю что либо в pom.xml и заново пишу, нажимаю import settings то только после этого проект можно запустить, до этого выдает ошибку что не может найти fxml файл для JavaFx приложения, потому что по логике не описана структура приложения так как он не видит pom.xml а потом все норм

Comment: @Youlfey настройки автоимпорта у мавена включены?

Comment: Всё я исправил, это был косяк idea, сделал те же самые действия что и обычно, нажал save all закрыл проект, раньше без save all закрывал, но вроде должно автоматически сохранять.